# 3 friends A, B and C got a photograph clicked. then probability that B is standing at the central position, if A is standing at the left corner

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Three friends A, B and C got their photograph clicked. Find the
probability that B is standing at the central position, given that A is
standing at the left corner.

Now, This is obviously a case of conditional probability
so if the event that B is in the centre is $E_1$ and the event that A is on the left is $E_2$
then

$ P(E_1|E_2) = \frac{P(E_1 \cap E_2)}{P(E_2)} $which is $\frac{1/2}{1/3}=\frac{3}{2}$

which is obviously wrong

where am I messing up?

Comment: Why is $P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: If A is on the left, there are only two spots left, of which, B can oly chose one, which is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You have 2 combinations where $a$ is positioned  at the left corner: $\color{blue}{abc, acb}$. One of the combinations has $b$ in the central: $\color{blue}{abc}$.

Comment: That's not $P(E_1 \cap E_2)$, that's actually $P(E_1 | E_2)$, the answer to the question! $P(E_1 \cap E_2)$ is the probability that A is in the left corner **and** B is in the central position; ask yourself, out of all the possible permutations, how many satisfy **both** of those conditions?

Comment: A common mistake: to confuse conditioning on event and intersection with the event.

Answer (score 5):

Let the event that $B$ is in the middle be $B_{mid}$ and the event that $A$ is at the left corner be $A_{left}$. So what you are trying to find is $P(B_{mid}| A_{left})$. By conditional probability we have, $$P(B_{mid}| A_{left})=\frac{P(B_{mid}\cap A_{left})}{P(A_{left})} $$

Consider the event $B_{mid}\cap A_{left}$, the only possible arrangement of the friends here is $ABC$. So the **probability** of the arrangement of $ABC$ happening out of the total number of arrangements is $\frac{1}{3!}$. So now we know that $P(B_{mid}\cap A_{left}) = \frac{1}{3!}$.

Consider the event $A_{left}$, what arrangements are there such that $A$ is at the left corner? They are $A**$ where each $*$ can be $B$ or $C$, basically $ABC$ and $ACB$. So the number of arrangements where $A$ is at left corner is $2!$. Similarly we can conclude that $P(A_{left}) = \frac{2!}{3!}$.

Putting all information together we conclude that $$P(B_{mid}| A_{left})=\frac{\frac{1}{3!}}{\frac{2!}{3!}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $E_1\cap E_2$ is a **subset** of $E_2$, you should have $P(E_1\cap E_2) < P(E_2)$.

In other words, whenever $E_1\cap E_2$ is satisfied, $E_2$ is also satisfied.

Just by writing out the options:

- $ABC$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is true.
- $ACB$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is not true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is not true.
- $BAC$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is not true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is not true.
- $BCA$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is not true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is not true.
- $CAB$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is not true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is not true.
- $CBA$: $E_1$ is true, $E_2$ is true, therefore, $E_1\cap E_2$ is not true.